# Create groupings based off of multiple categorical variables in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe of people with columns age ("old" or "young"), gender ("male" or "female"), and education ("no high school", "high school", or "college"). I want to group people into 12 groupings based off of these columns. The following code gets me what I want, but I was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way in Pandas to do this?

```
i = 1
df['group'] = 0
for a in ['old', 'young']:
    for g in ['male', 'female']:
        for e in ["no high school", "high school", "college"]:
            df.loc[((df.age == a) &
                    (df.gender == g) &
                    (df.education == e)), 'group'] = i
            i = i + 1
```

Comment: Anytime you talk about grouping a dataframe, it's worth looking at [DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.factorize`:

```
cats = ['age', 'gender', 'education']
df['group'] = pd.factorize(df[cats].apply(frozenset, axis=1))[0]
print(df)

# Output:
     age  gender       education  group
0    old  female         college      0
1    old    male     high school      1
2    old    male  no high school      2
3    old    male         college      3
4    old    male  no high school      2
5  young    male     high school      4
6    old    male         college      3
7    old  female  no high school      5
8    old  female  no high school      5
9    old  female  no high school      5
```

Comment: `groupby.ngroup` seems more straightforward, no? ;)

Comment: I knew there is something with `groupby`. You're the right answer!

Comment: Yours work nevertheless, but likely not as efficiently ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if I understand correctly:

```
df['group'] = df.groupby(['age', 'gender', 'education']).ngroup()
```